# selinuxfs and plymouth-upstart-bridge , error logs on ubuntu 14.04 (embedded)

Tags: 14.04, plymouth, selinux

I'm bringing up ubuntu 14.04 on beagleboard-xm from [RCN](http://eewiki.net/display/linuxonarm/BeagleBoard)'s site .

But on booting I see a set of logs , want to know what is it and how can i fix/disable this?

I'm totally confused, please help

```
Mount failed for selinuxfs on /sys/fs/selinux:  No such file or directory
[    5.922973] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process (69) terminated with status 1
[    5.954162] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process ended, respawning
[    6.082458] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process (79) terminated with status 1
[    6.091094] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process ended, respawning
[    6.106536] init: ureadahead main process (72) terminated with status 5
[    6.198150] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process (84) terminated with status 1
[    6.206817] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process ended, respawning
[    6.688293] init: mounted-proc main process (96) terminated with status 1
```

Comment: I'm seeing this same thing randomly today. Did you fix it somehow?

Comment: Sorry! I didn't fixed it

Comment: Bump. Any news? I'm "enjoying" this too.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this problem:

```
init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process ended, respawning
```

Try adding this line to the end of `etc/init/plymouth-upstart-bridge.conf`:

```
post-stop exec sleep 2
```

Sources:

- http://www.unrelatedshit.com/2014/07/30/kvm-too-fast-for-plymouth-upstart-bridge/
- ["respawning too fast, stopped". How to make UPSTART disable for 5 mins?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52309/respawning-too-fast-stopped-how-to-make-upstart-disable-for-5-mins)